# Question about everywhere differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose function $f$ is defined on $(0,1)$, and differentiable everywhere. If for almost every $x$, we have $|f'(x)|=1$, can we conclude that $f$ is a linear function, that is for all $x$, $f'(x)\equiv 1$ or$f'(x)\equiv -1$?

I think this is related to the intermediate value property of derivatives. If "for almost every" is modified as "for every", then it's obviously true. All I can get is that, the points where derivative is continuous forms a dense open set. Then I don't know how to progress.